# How to create pathauto same stackoverflow.com

Tags: drupal, pathauto

I know that stackoverflow.com uses the module pathauto. I would like to use pathauto in drupal to create pathauto uris. But I don't know how to do this.

Example: **domain.com/node/1** after using pathauto then **domain.com/article/1/title-node**

Now I want to go to **domain.com/article/1/???** then still it shows node 1 instead of show page not found.

Comment: So...? Did you solve your problem with any of the answers provided below? Are you still in difficult with this? Or... ?

Comment: By the way, StackOverflow doesn't use Drupal - it's based on ASP.NET MVC framework.

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT - I got a better idea**

I'm leaving my original answer below, but I think I got a better idea... you could implement [`hook_init()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_init/6) in a custom module of yours or [`custom_url_rewrite_inbound()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/custom_url_rewrite_inbound/6) in settings.php in order to strip your page request of the hyphened part, so that the url `/article/1/my-title` gets changed to `/article/1` all the times. The alias from node/XXX to article/XXX would still be done by pathauto.

**My original answer was:**

I don't know if there is a module that already does that, but achieve what you want is quite easy. You should implement your own version of [`hook_menu()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_menu/6) defining the function that will be triggered by an URL starting with "article" (for example "article/1/title-node").

For hook_menu, each bit separated by a slash is an argument that can be passed to the callback, so you will want to pass to the callback the number (so that the callback will load the proper node) and discard everything else.

Assuming you are using Drupal 6 Your menu item definition should look something like:

```
$item['article'] = array(
  'title' => 'My URL article redirect',
  'page callback' => 'name_of_my_callback_function',
  'page arguments' => array(1), //this passess the second bit of the URL
  'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: +1 - both are good solutions. In case this is needed for a heavy traffic site, the newer suggestion (stripping last part before processing) could also be done by means of `custom_url_rewrite_inbound` (http://api.drupal.org/api/function/custom_url_rewrite_inbound/6) instead of `hook_init()`. That would save some processing cycles, as the adjustment would happen before any other path processing, but at the price of having to put that somewhat weird 'pseudo hook' into settings.php.

Comment: If the paths are reliable enough (e.g. no non article page starting with 'article/[number]'), it could be even more effective to do the rewriting completely outside of Drupal/PHP by means of `mod_rewrite`. Probably most effective, but harder to maintain in case of changes.

Comment: @Hendrik: added your suggestion on custom\_url\_rewrite\_inbound() to the answer (and upvoted your comment! ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that with pathauto since all it does is creating aliases for your URLs. So you have to use an URL like http://example.com/article/1/title exactly as it was generated.

Stack Overflow goes a slightly different way in the sense that they simply ignore whatever comes as question title in the URL. They can do that since the URL parser is entirely different. For Drupal you may want to look for another module or roll your own. Pathauto just taps into the normal URL aliases and auto-generates them for you. No more, no less.

A [search for modules which deal with URLs](http://drupal.org/project/modules?text=url) on drupal.org yields quite a few matches. Some of them might do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I am going on the assumption that what you want to do is have an url structure like `http://example.com/article/ID/title` where the `title` part is pretty much ignored and it will go to `http://example.com/article/ID` no matter what is entered for `title`.
What you *could* do is set up a ***view*** that has the path `http://example.com/article` which accepts `ID` as an argument which is used to specify an individual article - most likely by the nid. It should then ignore anything that comes after it.

Comment: That is a solution too. It makes sense if you use views for something else than this too... otherwise is like going bird-hunting like a bazooka. [views is a heavyweight module and it's not worth installing it if all you have to do is this simple trick] :)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried global redirect, which ensures you only see the aliased path?
http://drupal.org/project/globalredirect
and what about subpath alias? it allows you to use alias as subpaths also.
for example, say node/1 alias is blog/johndoe/my-first-post , you could edit it using blog/johndoe/my-first-post/edit
http://drupal.org/project/subpath_alias

i guess you can work with these modules.